# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning in Xcode8 beta6, swift3.0. Still exists in Xcode8 GM

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode8 beta6, swift3.0, and get a compile warning as following:

```
Some object files have incompatible Objective-C category definitions. Some category 
metadata may be lost. All files containing Objective-C categories should be built using the 
same compiler.
```

Still exists in Xcode8 GM!

Comment: More info: https://twitter.com/steipete/status/765642650087292928

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39975404/73195